# SQL: order by two columns and get the firsts rows with equal values in 2-nd column

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table sorted by 1, 2 columns. And I need to get the first row from the top and all succeeding rows while their values of 2-nd column is the same as value of the first row.

F.e I have data sample:

```
select * from sample
order by ID desc, date desc

ID   Date
---  ----
45   NULL
44   NULL
40   01/01/10
35   NULL
32   04/05/08
```

I need to get the first two rows (with `id in (45, 44)`), because 2-nd row have `Date = NULL`.

If I'd had data sample:

```
ID   Date
---  ----
45   NULL
44   NULL
40   NULL
35   NULL
32   04/05/08
```

I will need to get the first 4 rows (with `id in (45, 44, 40, 35)`).

I can't make query to resolve my issue. I considered about using `row_number()` and `rank()`, but I can't adapt they for me purpose.
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Try `order by date,ID asc/decs`. This will first sort by second column and then by first (if you need this second sort at all).

Comment: Why wouldn't you get id = 35 in the first case?

Comment: its easy Gordon because u have different date column before 35 `40   01/01/10`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you can do something like this:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select t
from t cross join
     (select t.*
      from t
      order by id desc
      limit 1
     ) tt
order by (case when t.date = tt.date or t.date is null and t2.date is null then 1 else 2 end),
         t.id desc;
```

Comment: Cross join? The result will be bigger then source table.

Comment: @Vikora . . . LOL.  Not if the `limit 1` is included (as I had originally intended).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I concocted something like this, but it doesnt look elegantly.

```
select *
from (
   select *,
       sum(rank_date) over (partition by rank_date order by ID desc) as sm
   from (
       select *
            ,rank() over(order by DATE desc nulls first) rank_date
            ,row_number() over(order by ID desc) rank_id
       from sample
    ) ss
) s
where sm = row_number
```